# Using unsigned chars in C for data representation

Tags: c, opencv, character-encoding, char

Here is a function that I don't completely understand and I would like to completely understand:

```
/**
 * Returns: the label of a vertex in the given image at location (x, y).
 *          0 = unlabeled vertex at location (x, y)
 *          1 = background label at location (x, y)
 *          2 = object/foreground label at location (x, y)
 */
int getLabelAtVertexXY(IplImage* image, int x, int y) {
uchar* data = (uchar*) image->imageData + y * image->widthStep + 3 * x;
if (data[2] < 128 && data[1] < 128)
    return 0;
else if (data[1] > data[2])
    return 1; // TODO: data[1] holds probability in background starting at 128-255?
else
    return 2; 
}
```

Here is what I do get: each pixel of the image is being labeled 0, 1, or 2. How is that information being stored in a `unsigned char` pointer `data`?

I realize that an `unsigned char` can represent the numbers from 0 to 255 but what part of the `unsigned char` does `data[1]` retrieve?

Comment: Pixels can have values from 0-255 (which conveniently fits in a single unsigned byte)

Comment: You aren't looking at enough of the code. Somewhere, probably at the definition of IplImage, is an explanation of the encoding of the bytes of imageData.

Answer (score 1):

To understand how information is stored you need implementation of IplImage.

data is actually a pointer to unsigned char. No one said that it will be only 1 char. It could be array of chars. So data[1] is the 2-nd element in array.

Also, according to me the + operator do not do sum of number, it makes sum pointer addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like each pixel in that image is 3 bytes (as indicated by the 3*x when setting up the data pointer).

So data[0], data[1], data[2] are each of those 3 bytes, each of them an unsigned integer between 0 and 255 ?